# "Zu Hause arbeitet Peter am Wochenende gerne" oder "Zu Hause arbeitet Peter gerne am Wochenende"?

Tags: sentence-structure

"Zu Hause arbeitet Peter am Wochenende gerne" oder "Zu Hause arbeitet Peter gerne am Wochenende"? Was ist richtig und warum? Ich denke, dass ersteres wegen "TEKAMOLO" (TEmporal, KAusal, MODal und LOkal) richtig ist. "Am Wochenende" ist "TE" und "gerne" ist "MO".

Comment: Ist Zuhause nicht Lokal und nach der Logik wäre beides falsch? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Beides ist richtig, aber die Sätze haben eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung. Der Unterschied liegt darin, welcher Teil der enthaltenen Information bereits bekannt ist, und welcher Teil neu dazu kommt.

> Zu Hause arbeitet Peter am Wochenende gerne.

Hier ist bereits bekannt, dass Peter am Wochenende zu Hause arbeitet. Die neue Information ist, dass er das gerne tut.

> Zu Hause arbeitet Peter gerne am Wochenende.

Hier ist bereits bekannt, dass Peter zu Hause arbeitet. Die neue Information ist hier: Wenn Peter zu Hause arbeitet, tut er das bevorzugt (gerne) am Wochenende.

Man könnte auch sagen, im ersten Beispiel ist betont, dass Peter *gerne* am Wochenende zu Hause arbeitet. Im zweiten Beispiel ist betont, dass Peter gerne *am Wochenende* zu Hause arbeitet.

Generell ist die Satzstellung im Deutschen recht flexibel. Es gibt "Standardsatzstellungen", die keine besondere Betonung mitbringen. Das sind die Regeln, die man häufig in Lehrbüchern findet. Will man aber einen Satzteil besonders betonen (zum Beispiel, um zu verdeutlichen, dass das die neue Information im Satz ist), kann man durchaus vom "Standardfall" abweichen.

Am Rande bemerkt, etwas gerne zu tun ist gerade ein [gerne genommenes Thema](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67383/ich-mag-katzen-gern-or-ich-mag-gern-katzen) hier ;)

Comment: Also für mich klingen beide Sätze falsch weil ich nach "zuhause arbeitet er am" etwas erwarte, woran Peter arbeitet, und nicht das Wochenende. Die Information ist, dass er am Wochenende gerne zu Hause arbeitet, und ich finde das ist in beiden Sätzen schlecht gelöst. Peter arbeitet am Wochenende gerne zu Hause.

Comment: Alex, auch Dein Satz hat wieder eine andere Bedeutung, und zwar wäre er die passende Antwort auf die Frage: »Wo arbeitet Peter am Wochenende gerne?«. Die beiden Sätze aus der ursprünglichen Frage haben einen anderen Schwerpunkt und setzen andere Informationen voraus, wie von Henning beschrieben. Vielleicht ergänzt Henning seine Antworten gerne an Montagen. ;-)

Comment: Für mich wirkt der erste Beispielsatz auch merkwürdig, aber aus einem anderen Grund: "Zu Hause arbeitet Peter am Wochenende gerne" kombiniert viel bereits bekannte Information mit sehr wenig neuer Information. Das fühlt sich ungleichgewichtig an. Ich möchte die Antwort aber ungern um weitere Varianten erweitern, das würde die Antwort mMn ziemlich unhandlich machen.

Comment: Naja, ich widerspreche. Egal wie ich die Bausteine platziere bleibt die Information und die Bedeutung gleich. Nur die beiden Beispielsätze klingen falsch.

Comment: @Alex Die Information bleibt gleich, die Bedeutung aber nicht. Wie bereits in der Antwort angesprochen, ändert sich die Betonung, die Gewichtung der einzelnen Teilinformationen.